# What is the difference between calling components in JSX and passing them as children props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

So I was navigating on web, and I saw a senior developer talking about that most of junior developers don't know the difference between calling components in **JSX and passing them as children props.** And honestly I don't know the difference.
Can any one tell me the difference between them, is it performance, is it the architecture...

Thank you.

Comment: it is about architecture, and most likely about the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle. If you would provide a link to the discussion, one could actually answer it

Comment: It's not really a discussion, he just said that most of junior developers don't know the difference between calling components in JSX and passing them as children props. Which confused me, because he didn't give a context. 
Thank you so much for the information.

Answer (score 1):

So according to the information I got I think the best information on the topic is found [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html) and [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html) .

Main difference is probably the scope in which the components are declared, so you can declare click handlers in a different way.